# JPA get MIN/MAX attribute of connected entity

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class HostMachine {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Application.class)
    private Set<Application> applications;

    // getters and setters
}
```

.

```
@Entity
public class Application {
    @Basic
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BusinessCriticality businessCriticality;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = HostMachine.class, mappedBy = "applications")
    private Set<HostMachine> hosts;

    // getters and setters
}
```

A classic `ManytoMany` relationship. **Now I want to see the highest businessCriticality of connected applications on the host.**

I tried using a `@Transient` attribute and setting it after every single query that returns hosts, but for collections I'd need to do a query for every single element, so this is very un-performant and straight ugly in code.

Then I tried using Hibernate's `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("SELECT MIN(a.businessCriticality) FROM Application a")
private BusinessCriticality businessCriticality;
```

but this gives me a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`, even though I can execute the query in an MySQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put native SQL query inside `@Formula` value. It will be then used to create select query when Hibernate queries for this entity/property.

In your case it should be something like that (it depends on naming strategy you use):

```
@Formula("(select max(a.business_criticality) from application a " +
         "join host_machine_application hma on a.id = hma.application_id " +
         "where hma.host_machine_id = id)")"
```

And it all will work if only `a.business_criticality` can be placed inside `max/min` (for MySQL it can be - but will it work correctly for your needs?)

Comment: The secret was the braces inside the string. Thanks!